# What the need for abstract class here?

Tags: oop

One of the interview questions which they asked me very recently.

> What is an abstract class in C#?
> Abstract Class - is a class which cannot be instantiated & can include abstract or instance methods, constructors etc.
>
> Instance methods can be used for implementing common functionality for all derived classes which inherits this abstract class.

Ok...Now the question is why we need an abstract class here for implementing the common functionality. The same common functionality i can put in a base class and let the derived class can access the base class methods..right?? if thats the case, instead of having an abstract class.. can i go for base class?? or to put the common functionality in abstract class and let the derive class do access those methods?

If my base class can solve the implementing of common functionality, then why do we need an abstract class for common functionality???

Need help in proper understanding....

Comment: An abstract class _is_ a base class. It is an expert at being base-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An abstract class *is* a base class - but it's a base class which typically has some abstract members. This allows you to write code in the abstract class which *calls* those abstract members, but without any implementation... it then forces concrete classes deriving from the abstract class to implement those members.

The benefits of having an abstract class rather than just a concrete base class where some members throw `NotImplementException`s are:

- Derived classes are forced (at compile-time) to implement the relevant members
- Clients can't just create an instance of the base class; they have to use a concrete class which provides the appropriate "missing" members.

As an example, the other day I wrote an abstract class class extending `JsonConverter` in Json.NET. The aim was for it to be a base class for any converters for structs within my project - it would handle all the nullable type conversions (and deserializing empty JSON to a null value), leaving the derived classes free to *just* concentrate on the type-specific part. Have a look at it ([`NodaConverterBase`](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/source/browse/src/NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet/NodaConverterBase.cs)) and see if it makes things any clearer.

Comment: ... thus allowing the existence of "polimorphism", wich is one of the most important things of Object Oriented programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me to understand the need for abstract class

Answer (score 1):

An Abstract Class is used as a Base class. There are times when you may want to have common functionality be implemented but not directly instantiate an instance of your Base Class Type so you would use an Abstract Class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way, if you were writing an app to keep track of zoo animals you would have classes for Monkey, Elephant, Crocodile, etc...  They are all animals, so you would have them inherit a base class of Animal (because they all need basic functionality like eating, breathing, etc...).  But you would never have an animal that's just an animal, so you would make Animal abstract because you would never need an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky phrase is

```
"partial implementation."
```

In addition to what you mention in your post, the abstract class does not have to implement all the functions AND the children MUST implement the unimplemented functions or be themselves declared abstract.